# Format rsyslog messages - remove IP of logserver

Tags: regex, logging, sed, rsyslog

Our Archive-Server is getting Logs send by a few Log-Server - those write their own IP in every message they forward to the Archive-Server. Now I wanted to "cut" their IP-Adress and "src@" from every Logmessage with the rsyslog configuration of my Archive-Server.

Example:

192.168.0.12 is one of my Log-Server | Foo is the "real" Source-IP translated in its DNS-Name

- wrong [ Aug 23 10:00:01 192.168.0.12 src@Foo logdata logdata ]
- right [ Aug 23 10:00:01 Foo logdata logdata ]

At first I thought I could go with "FIELDS" and whitespace as a delimiter, but I think I would cut the DNS-Name of my real Source-IP as well, when I wanted to remove src@. Would love to go with sed, if that's possible, but I dont know how to implement that within my rsyslog.conf

```
sed 's/\(192.168.0.12 @src\)//'
```

should work.

_________UPDATE________

There is a promising looking function called "replace" but I can't seem to get it to work at all.

https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/rainerscript/functions.html#replace-str-substr-to-replace-replace-with

```
if ( $fromhost-ip == '192.168.0.12' ) then {

   replace($msg, "@src", " ")
   -/var/log/foo.log
   stop
}
```

Msgs are written withing foo.log - but nothing is replaced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with a template. Since the logserver is inserting his own IP, I can just "remove" %hostname% and it's done.

```
template template_name,"%timegenerated% %progname% %msg%"   
if fromhost-ip == '192.168.0.12' then {   
   /var/log/foo.log,template_name   
   stop

}
```